# Iterative Calculation Over Multiple Rows and Inputs (Excel / Lambda)

Tags: excel, recursion, iteration

I have a workbook with 2 sheets. One sheet (S1) has multiple rows with column C1 that is calculated by a value in the next column C2 which is a result calculated on separate sheet (S2).

Sheet 1    C1    C2
Row 1  1000   1 <-( S1R1C2 value calculated from S2D2. S2D2 result is based on input value S1R1C1 input to S2D1)
Row 2  1250   3 <-( S1R2C2 value calculated from S2D2. S2D2 result is based on input value S1R2C1 input to S2D1)

Sheet 2
D1 1000 <-- This value currently is manually input however ideally should be dynamically pulled   from the row range S1C1R1...S1C1Rn)

```
 D2 1 <-- This value is the calculated result that relies on the value S2D1 taken from S1C1R1...S1C1Rn
```

I would like to iterate over every row and process the input of S2D1 from S1 for the calculation by populating (dynamically) S2D1 (from row range S1C1R1...S1C1Rn) and return the calculated value S2D2 by  iterating over the row range S1C1R1...S1C1Rn).

1. Take value from S1R1C1 populate S2D1 calculate S2D2 --> return value and populate S1R1C2, iterate to next row S1R2, take S1R2C1 value --> input S2D1 calculate S2D2  --> return value and populate S1R2C2.....etc. etc. until the end of S1C1R1...S1C1Rn.

I have tried to use solver, and the What If function, however both of those work when the target result is known. In this case I do not know what the the target value is and unable to use Solver/What-if. I activated Iterative calculations in Excel.

The last thing that looked promising was the Lambda function coupled with the Rows function to process on a row by row basis. Or perhaps a VBA script that will process all the rows with a button click perhaps.

This is what I have in S1R1C2 = byrow(S1C1R1...S1C1Rn,LAMBDA(row,S2D2)). Maybe this is the right direction clearly what is missing is the row input S2D1 which is required for S2D2 to be calculated.

Thank you for any help in advance.

-JZ